# Jmeter - Time by Jmeter sampler and time by curl ( time_total) is different for same call

Tags: jmeter

I am new to Jmeter . I have a http sampler in Jmeter that gives average response time for 10 iterations as 
854 ms.

Then I am using curl to get the time for same call like this and everytime I am getting 1500 ms .

```
curl -w %{time_total}\\n  https://someapicall.
```

Question is does any one know why there may be such a difference between these two above calls and how to correct this.

Answer (score 1):

This is because by default JMeter reuses the cached SSL context between iterations, so it is faster.

To disable this behaviour set in user.properties:

- https.use.cached.ssl.context=false

Another possible explanation is warmup. In your config jmeter has warmed up on first request while curl does everytime the full reinit, to compare you would need to keep the curl session opened, something similar to this:

- http://php.net//manual/fr/book.curl.php

You may try ab to compare with jmeter.

Comment: Forget to mention in my post I do have https.use.cached.ssl.context=false in my jmeter.properties but not in user.properties. That is correct right

Comment: if it's uncommented in jmeter.properties then the reason is different